# F12 key not working in asp.net Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> shortcut keys are not working in Visual Studio 2019.

I have tried to reset keyboard in Tools -> Options ... also tried to change the Resharper schema from "none" to "Visual Studio" - but nothing worked!

On right click, I can go to definition, but shortcut keys are not working! Set brightness every time I press <kbd>F12</kbd> instead of going to definition!

Comment: Do you have function lock enabled on your keyboard..?

Comment: It seems your computer has F12 remaped to change brightness instead of F12.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb it behaves same with Function key locked or unlocked! Any other ideas?

Comment: @Disha is your shortcut properly mapped? If you go to Tools > Options, then under Environment > Keyboard is Edit.GoToDefinition mapped to F12?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb yes, its mapped properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a laptop, you might consider one of the following options:

- Press **FN+F10** or **FN+F12**, instead of F10 and F12;
- Acessing your laptop BIOS settings and switching FN default behavior.

For further details on FN key, check https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/fn.htm

Comment: It worked as Fn+F10 . Thank you !

Comment: Hi @Disha. I am glad it helped. Now you should consider marking  my answer as Usefull/BestAnswer, if it the case.